# Bash remove everything after </html>

Tags: replace, sed

One of my clients' sites has been hacked, and there is iframe injection in every file. However, the iframe injection is always after the closing `</html>` tag.

Is there an easy way using Bash to remove everything after the `</html>` tag using something like sed?

E.g.:

```
</html>
p
<nofollow><iframe src="http://xxxxx.com/local.html" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe></nofollow>
p
<nofollow><iframe src="http://xxxxx.com/local.html" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe></nofollow>
```

Comment: everything from </html> to the end of the current line or to the end of the file or to some other delimiter? Post some small sample input and expected output.

Comment: To the end of the file. I'll post an example...

Comment: checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13994734/1006989) to remove lines until EOF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just quit when you hit the  line:

```
sed -i '/<\/html>/q' file
```

Comment: This seems to print out the result, but is there a way to overwrite the existing file with the output? Like a sed `'s/.../.../g'`?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

```
 sed -i '/<\/html>/,$d;$a <\/html>' yourfile
```

*Updated to delete lines until the end of the file*

Comment: That would just delete anything after `</html>` on that same line. Didn't sound at all like what the OP wanted and wouldnt work on his posted sample input so I'm surprised he accepted that as the answer!

Comment: Actually just noticed I get this: `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: @JamesHadley yep James answer suits more your needs, note that you need to scape the backslashes in the pattern

Comment: `sed: 1: "/<\/html>/,": expected context address`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21537/discussion-between-x-jacobs-and-james-hadley)

Comment: You need to use single quotes not double or bash will interpret $d as the contents of variable d. You also need to modify the command to leave `</html>` in the file.

Comment: @EdMorton right, did the test with single quotes, besides this method will delete any text before the `</html>` tag if it's in the same line...