# bash remove everything DIRECTLY after html

Tags: bash, sed

My question is almost identical to this one: [Bash remove everything after </html>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994654/bash-remove-everything-after-html). However, the answer

```
sed -i '/<\/html>/,$d;$a <\/html>' yourfile
```

is stripping the  tag as well. I've tried various of the sed command and | piping another command to re-add the closing  tag, but nothing has worked.

In short, i'm trying to remove everything after the  tag, even if on the same line or not.

Comment: `sed '/<\/html>/q' infile` works fine

Comment: No, it's not stripping the end tag, or rather, it's adding it back at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
sed -n '1,/<\/html>/{s!</html>.*!</html>!;p}' input
```

Another:

```
sed -e 's!</html>.*!</html>!' -e '/<\/html>/q' input
```

Comment: perreal, thanks. unfortunately, neither one of these modify the file. Also even when i do use -i. 

- The first approach removes everything from the next line forward after the </html> tag (leaving the code after - but on the same line as - the </html>

- The second approach can't find the file no matter how i layout -i/-e flags. However, running the commands separately DOES WORK! Is there a way to run these together as one command (recursively) on a directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -n '0,/<\/html>/{s!</html>.*!</html>!;p};q' input
```

This removes anything after `</html>` on the same line and deletes all subsequent lines (just a `;q` added to perreal's first way).
`-i` works fine for me (GNU sed 4.2.1).